# Not the excpected hash from the scrypt algo

Tags: vb.net, hash, hex, scrypt, litecoin

i am using this scrypt from [here](https://github.com/replicon/Replicon.Cryptography.SCrypt#:%7E:text=Replicon.Cryptography.SCrypt%20This%20library%20is%20a%20wrapper%20for%20the,routines%20written%20in%20C%20and%20distributed%20by%20Colin.) inside my vb application

I tried this code to hash a hex string:

```
Imports Replicon.Cryptography.SCrypt

Public Class Form1


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim ss() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(TextBox1.Text)

        RichTextBox1.Text = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(SCrypt.DeriveKey(ss, ss, 1024, 1, 1, 32))


    End Sub
End Class
```

The hex string inside the textbox:

```
TextBox1.text = "01000000f615f7ce3b4fc6b8f61e8f89aedb1d0852507650533a9e3b10b9bbcc30639f279fcaa86746e1ef52d3edb3c4ad8259920d509bd073605c9bf1d59983752a6b06b817bb4ea78e011d012d59d4"
```

It gives me this:

`r3Î<ÛãhšÏ-$:8´"ýäP+°‡ W«&‰Â`

The excpected result after inversing the little endian is this:

`0000000110c8357966576df46f3b802ca897deb7ad18b12f1c24ecff6386ebd9`

I think the problem is the byte conversion, string conversion?

Help is appreciated

Thanks to all.

Comment: The output of `SCrypt.DeriveKey()` is a sequence of randomish bytes. They are not the encoding of string, so decoding them as a string doesn't make any sense. There is nothing wrong with just leaving them as bytes but if you must have a string then encode the bytes with a base64- or hex-encoder. You must then decode them when they are used again.

Comment: Thank you i update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

The code is:

```
Imports Replicon.Cryptography.SCrypt
Imports System.Globalization
Imports System.Text

Public Class Form1


    Public Shared Function Btog(ByVal ba() As Byte) As String
        Dim hex As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2)
        Dim b As Byte
        For Each b In ba
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b)
        Next
        Return hex.ToString()
    End Function



    Public Function HexDecode(ByVal s As String) As Byte()
        Return HexDecode(s, 0)
    End Function

    Public Function HexDecode(ByVal s As String, ByVal paddingBytes As Integer) As Byte()
        If s Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("s")
        End If

        If s.IndexOf(":"c) > -1 Then
            s = s.Replace(":", "")
        End If

        If (s.Length Mod 2) <> 0 Then
            Throw New FormatException("parameter 's' must have an even number of hex characters")
        End If

        Dim result As Byte() = New Byte(s.Length \ 2 + (paddingBytes - 1)) {}
        For i As Integer = 0 To result.Length - paddingBytes - 1
            result(i) = Byte.Parse(s.Substring(i * 2, 2), NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier)
        Next
        Return result
    End Function
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click



        RichTextBox1.Text = Btog(SCrypt.DeriveKey(HexDecode(TextBox1.Text), HexDecode(TextBox1.Text), 1024, 1, 1, 32))


    End Sub
End Class
```